# Finding a Hamiltonian Circuit using Nearest-neighbor algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

Correct me if I'm wrong but can't the nearest neighbor algorithm be used to find a Hamiltonian Circuit in an arbitrary graph and hence proved P = NP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nearest neighbor algorithm as I understand it (repeatedly select a neighboring vertex that hasn't been visited yet and travel to that vertex) does not guarantee that you will find a circuit even if one exists.  For example consider the graph with vertices A,B,C,D with edges AB, AC, AD, BC and CD (a complete graph on 4 vertices with edge BD removed).  Starting at A, you travel to C.  You can then travel to either B or D, at which point your only choice is to go back to A.  So if you go from A to C, you can't complete the loop and construct a Hamiltonian circuit even though one exists.